# accuracy: precision: recall: 0.9020 are always the same

Tags: keras, metrics

I have in my test dataset `5960` images:
and I got results metrics:

```
TP: 5116.0  
FP: 794.0   
TN: 5116.0  
FN: 794.0

len(testX) = 5960
```

One epoch's log:

```
185/185 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.4095 - 
                                           tp: 5127.0000 - fp: 783.0000 - 
                                           tn: 5127.0000 - fn: 783.0000 - 
                                           accuracy: 0.8675 - precision: 0.8675 - 
                                           recall: 0.8675 - auc: 0.9200
```

Load images:

```
label = 1 if label == "positive" else 0
...
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
# convert the labels from integers to vectors
testY = to_categorical(testY, num_classes=2)
```

I used keras.metrics and I have only two labels: (0 and 1).
What did I wrong?

```
loss, tp, fp, tn, fn, accuracy, precision, recall, auc = model.evaluate(testX, testY, verbose=1)
```

I think when image1 have label '1',

1. it add +1 to TP ( label '1' )
2. +1 to TN ( label '0' ).

My model:

```
    model.add(Conv2D(20, (5, 5), padding="same",
        input_shape=inputShape))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    # second set of CONV => RELU => POOL layers
    model.add(Conv2D(50, (5, 5), padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    # first (and only) set of FC => RELU layers
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(500))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.05))

    # softmax classifier
    model.add(Dense(classes))
    model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

Comment: Can you add your model?

Comment: Done. I added a model.

Comment: You applied one hot encoding operation to the labels? What is the loss function? There is something wrong. `len(testX) = 5960` should be equal to TP + TN + FP + FN

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. But I don't know why...

Comment: I added some more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply one-hot-encoding for binary classification these metrics mess up. Here is an example:

Your labels looks like this after one hot encoding: `[ ... [1,0], [0,1], [1,0] ... ]`

If you pay attention your `TP` equals `TN`. When it is correctly predicted as class 0, it is `TP` for class 0, also `TN` for class 1. That's why they are equal.

Don't apply one hot encoding and change:

```
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
```

Also loss should be `binary_crossentropy`.